# Laravel show products with child categories

Tags: php, laravel

I have MainController with code:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with('category')->paginate(15);

    return view('main', compact('products'));
}
```

In blade:

```
                       <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="th-1">Name</h2></th>
                                <th class="th-2">Count <!--<span><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>--></span></th>
                                <th class="th-3">Price <!--<span><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>--></span></th>
                                <th class="th-4">Sales <!--<span><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>--></span></th>
                                <th class="th-5"></th>
                            </tr>
                            {{-- {{ dd($products->groupBy('category_id')) }} --}}

                            @include('products')
                        </table>
        <div class="pagination mt-3">
            {{ $products->links() }}
        </div>
```

In products blade:

```
@forelse($products->groupBy('category.title') as $title => $prods)
{{-- @forelse($products as $product) --}}
<tr class="category">
    <td colspan="5">{{ $title }}</td>
</tr>

@foreach($prods as $product)
<tr>
        <td>
            <div class="icon float-left mr-2">
                <span class="{{ $product->category->slug ?? '' }}"><i class="{{ $product->category->icon['font'] ?? 'far fa-file-alt' }}" @isset($product->category->icon['color']) style="color: {{ $product->category->icon['color'] }}" @endisset></i></span>
            </div>
            <p class="mb-0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ $product->description }}">
                {!! $product->title !!}
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $product->product_count }}
        </td>
        <td>
            @if($product->discount)
                <del class="text-danger">{{ $product->oldPrice }} $.</del>
                {{ $product->price }} $. <span class="text-muted">/ 1 cnt.</span>
            @else
                {{ $product->price }} $. <span class="text-muted">/ 1 cnt.</span>
            @endif
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $product->sales }}
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <a href="{{ route('showproduct', $product) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                Readmore
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

@empty
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">

            <p>-</p>

    </td>
</tr>
 @endforelse
```

In model Category I have relations `children`, and `parent`:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Now I get products on page:

**Category**
1. Product 1
2. Product 2
3. Product 3

**Another Category**
1. Product 1
2. Product 2
3. Product 3

How I can add child and get the result?

**Category**
1. Product
2. Product
-----**Category Child**
-----    1. Product
-----    2. Product

**Another Category**
1. Product
2. Product
-----**Category Child**
-----    1. Product
-----    2. Product
3. Product

***UPDATE***

Now I get duplicates:

**Category**
1. Product 1
2. Product 2
3. Product 3

**Another Category**
1. Product 1
2. Product 2
3. Product 3

How I can add child and get the result?

**Category**
1. Product
2. Product
-----**Category Child**
-----    1. Product
-----    2. Product

**Another Category**
1. Product
2. Product
3. Product

**Category Child**
  1. Product
  2. Product

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior with recursion. The main idea is to call a products partial when the parent product has children. The first thing to do is to send all `categories` to the view, not the `products`. So, in Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::paginate(15);

    return view('main', compact('categories'));
}
```

And then, in the view, you loop the categories in recursion. This is the main idea:

Products.blade:

```
//Code...
<h1>List</h1>
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    @include('partial', ['category' => $category])
@endforeach
//Code...
```

And then you can create a file called `partial.blade`:

```
{{ $category->title }}

@foreach ($category->products as $product)
    {!! $product->title !!}
    //Other attributes
@endforeach

@if ($category->children()->count() > 0)
    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
        @include('partial', ['category' => $child])
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The main idea is to call partial.blade when a specific category has children. So, you call it for every child again.

Comment: no, not working, I need get products, but not category children. `$product->category->children->products` not working. I have relation `products` on category model. But not working.. I get error: `Property [products] does not exist `

Comment: Ok, I did not understand the relations correctly. Try to edit the final if in `partial.blade` with my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry. But in model Category relation is: `products`. $product->category->children->products` need be.. But why error `Property [products] does not exist`?

Comment: Ok, I added category to product in the end of the answer.

Comment: Working. Thanks :))) But I have 1 problem. I get duplicate child category..

Comment: Nice to know it works... Now that I fully understand the problem, it would be better if the recursion was made with a foreach in the categories, not in products. It would be the same stuff, but the partial.blade.php file would check categories. Try to check if you can do this, or I could edit the file tomorrow.

Comment: Edit please. I get duplicates. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Check this new answer. I posted the main idea of the concept, and then you format it to your HTML/CSS. Look that is better to send categories instead of products, to achieve the behavior you want. Regards

Comment: Is this working without pagination? If it is working as you need, we can try to paginate it.

Comment: Yes. Working. Please help realease pagination products

Comment: I can think of two ways to paginate this. 1 - List categories and paginate the itens internally. The problem is that you can have a category with 1 product filling one entire page. 2 - Group everything by products, like you were doing in your original post. But this would require a lot of coding to group everything right in the view.
I would suggest that you use this main idea and apply it to one of those options. This recursion idea is the core of what you need, but unfortunately, I can't code everything here.